# How much time takes it to get a diagnosis of borreliosis/lyme disease?

Tags: infection, diagnosis, lyme-disease

I cannot find any source that clearly tells me how quickly a diagnosis for finding out wether someone carries borreliosis or not can be conducted (I hope it is clear what I mean, I have little medical experience so I this the best way I found to put it).

The question is in particular relevant to me because I suspect I carry borreliosis since 1,5 or 2 months[*] and I am now considering seeing a doctor in an hospital for this right tomorrow but only if a diagnosis can be done
quickly within hours with a simple blood test.

If it takes however a more elaborate analysis of my body fluids in order to find it out and if the analysis takes several days in order to have a diagnosis, then I leave it be and see my usual physician at Monday in order to drain some blood for sending it in. On the weekend, hospitals are severly understaffed here in Austria so I do not wanna annoy the staff there with a request that they cannot really conclude.

[*]If anyone is interested in why I suspect I carry it: First, the bite mark of the tick is still visible and sometimes itching (though the [usual red rashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyme_disease#Signs_and_symptoms) did never appear on my skin) and second, I have outbursts of sweat   without doing any physical exertion beforehand, suggesting that my immune system is under stress.

Comment: It is not a diagnsosis made in an hour. Don't waste the hospital's time.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE!  If you have a health issue you are worried about it is best to visit your doctor who can advise whether you need to go to the hospital.  This alleviates extra strain on hospital resources which could be used with other urgent cases.

Comment: I strongly doubt there will be any definitive test that will come back in less than a day, possibly even a week or more.

Comment: Update: I vistied a general practioner, she sent me to a lab were a bit of my blood got drained. The diagnosis will take several days they said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Two-step Laboratory Testing Process](https://www.cdc.gov/lyme/diagnosistesting/labtest/twostep/index.html) is recommended for Lyme decease detection. It takes several days depends on the laboratory to  make the test.

However in accordance to your post you were bitten by tick more than 30 days ago and you did not develop [later signs &symptoms](https://www.cdc.gov/lyme/signs_symptoms/index.html). So it gives evidences that the probability of the development of Lyme decease is quite low.